# How to programmatically determine we are on desktop and not on application server (to show a popup window)?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a java SE application which sits in system tray and shows a popup message thru JavaFX. Now I need to host this app in a cloud, so I converted it (project facets) to Dynamic Web Project and deployed it to Tomcat. Everything works fine - now entry point is not main(), but ServletContextListener. But at some point control goes to starting JavaFX and showing popup. So I would like to be able to code something like this:

```
if(onDesktop){
  startJavaFX();
  showMyPopupWnd();
}
```

If it helps, so far app is supposed to run only on Tomcat 7 and higher.

Besides, what is best way to maintain two versions of same app (desktop and App-Server web project)? Now I am working in two IDEs - Eclipse SE and Eclipse extends (two projects respectively - old SE and new extends with ServletContextListener entry point instead of main), but I understand that it is a bad idea to code two actually separate logic workflows...

Comment: Hard to imagine real-life software with such single-layer construction. Problem described here is only first and simplest. Use modularisation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a global boolean named e.g. `onDesktop` you only set to true in the main-method.

Regarding how to do it, you frequently split core logic into a separate module and then have a module for each target environment.  This is typically the point where you need to start to learn Maven.

Comment: agree. Maven is good tool for better planed software (and modularised software is older than maven)

Comment: @JacekCz Yes, modularized software is old.   But for a budding Java programmer who needs a direction to go I believe Maven is the best advice these days.

Comment: OK. I want say, hopeful cutting between modules is strictly intellectual process, by human. Tool is only tool

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether you are running in a headless environment using [GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#isHeadless--)

> Tests whether or not a display, keyboard, and mouse can be supported in this environment. If this method returns true, a HeadlessException is thrown from areas of the Toolkit and GraphicsEnvironment that are dependent on a display, keyboard, or mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be setting an environment variable for a different environment with respective value and access it from java application. Like for env variable, we can name like `envType` and you can put a value like `local` and `server`. You can access that variable from the java application using `System#getenv`.

```
String envType = System.getenv("envType")
if(envType.equals("local")){
  startJavaFX();
  showMyPopupWnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that embedding JavaFX code into a server WAR is a bad design, here is how to determine if your app is running on a server or not by checking the availability of `javax.servlet.ServletException` in the classpath.

```
public static boolean isDesktop()
{
    boolean isDesktop;
    try
    {
      Class.forName("javax.servlet.ServletException");
      isDesktop = false;
      log.info("This program runs on a server");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex);
    {
      isDesktop = true;
      log.info("This program runs on a desktop");
    }
    return isDesktop;
}
```